# can't use if/else inside react render method

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using React with Ant Design, but this is only a react issue.

I have a code like this:

```
  {
    title: "Group",
    dataIndex: "group",
    key: "group",
    render: text => (
     <a> {text} </a>
    )
  }
```

Not the `render: text => ()` which allows me to use html inside a js function (or jsx?)

but, if I try to put if/else logic I get always an error.

Right now I am using something stupid like this:

```
render: texts => (
  <span>
     {[""].map(text => {
      if(texts.includes(":")) {
       return (<b> {texts} </b>)
      }
    return (<a> {texts} </a>)
  })}
</span>
```

The questions is, is there a way to do it without using `[""].map()` and why won't simple if/else work

Comment: Please check this doc page: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why it's not possible:

- there is a difference between [Expressions versus statements](https://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html) in JS:

  > An expression produces a value ... a statement performs an action.
- the `{}` syntax allows [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx), but it does NOT allow embedding statements
- `if` is a statement

An equivalent expression, using a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to replace `if`:

```
render: texts => (
  <span>
     {texts.includes(":")
       ? <b>{texts}</b>
       : <a>{texts}</a>
     }
  </span>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `if/else` inside JSX, but you can either use a ternary expression inside the JSX or an `if/else` condition inside your function before returning some JSX. Here is an example of both:

```js
    {

      render: texts => (
        <span>
          { 
            texts.includes(":")
              ? <b> {texts} </b>
              : <a> {texts} </a>
          }
        </span>
      ),

      otherRender: texts => {
        if (texts.includes(":")) {
          return (
            <span><b> {texts} </b></span>
          )
        }
        return (
          <span><a> {texts} </a></span>
        )
      }

    }
```